# Magento 2.1.6 - Product Images not showing

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, magento2.1.6

The site is working fine but on installing Magento sample data, the product category list does not show the images, when i check the source of the image it does not exist in the Magento directory given, tried reinstalling the sample data still no joy.

Home page images show up and on the actual product page, images display perfectly.

Most of the commands i have already carried out such as deploying static content, magento:updgrade, cleaning cache, reindexing but still nothing.

I also use an extension which allows me to import data content, from thousands of categories, this still does not bring up the product images and source of an image is like this:

http://dev.modxpcit.co.uk/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857/https://media.stockinthechannel.com/pic/9pO1aTE6uku3cRWISiIveg.c-m.jpg

Why would there be another address next to the cache folder? again, this does not exist in the directory.

Answer (score 4):

Seems that this is a bug with 2.1.6 - this command fixed it, which should be done on production mode if you have a lot of products as it took 25 minutes to complete this bug:

```
bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```