# Magento 2 not generating images cache

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images

I have a **Magento 2.1.6** 
The folder `pub/media/catalog/product/cache` does **not get generated**.
All my products on the front end are showing broken images.
I have tried resetting the permissions numerous times, to no availability.

I tried flushing the caches, deploying static content, `catalog:images:resize` but nothing seems to help.

I cannot find any errors in the **Apache error.log** that would indicate what went wrong.

Comment: Did you tried this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172853/magento-2-1-6-product-images-not-showing

Comment: found the culprit. we had previously applied this patch https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170376/magento-2-unable-to-write-file-into-directory-access-forbidden and then we upgraded to PHP 7